# Parsing element in a ruby array

Tags: ruby, list, parsing

I like to parse string array and update value, what i have for example:

```
list= ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]
```

in the above list i want to search for "active" and edit its value, like if "active=0" i want to make it "active=1" , and if its "active=1" i want to make it "active=0".

```
What i am doing is , but its not correct ,, can someone assist in this:

list.each do |lists|
   if lists.include?("active=0")
      lists = "active=1"
   elsif list.include?("active=1")
      lists = "active=0"
   end
end
```

what i expect in the end if list contains active=0 , than output list = ["beam=0", "active=1", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"] and if list contains active=1, then output list = ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]

Comment: Why not use a hash, e.g. `hash = { beam: 0, active: 0, rate: 11, version: "4.1", delay: 5 }`. That way you could update via `hash[:active] = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a hash, it is much more suitable for this task.

If you cannot, then the problem with your code is that you are not updating the original value. You are just updating the variable used in the `#each` iterator.

One way to do what you want is this:

```rb
list = ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]

# convert to hash
hash = list.to_h { |x| x.split '=' }

# update any hash value
hash['active'] = hash['active'] == '0' ? '1' : '0'

# convert back to array
result = hash.map { |x| x.join '=' }
```

and, if for some reason, you wish to stay as close as possible to your original code, then you can use map instead of each. I do not recommend the below code for this case, since this is not good coding, but in case you have your reasons and this is for educational purposes only:

```rb
list = ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]
result = list.map do |item|
  case item
  when 'active=0' then 'active=1'
  when 'active=1' then 'active=0'
  else
    item
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting this error, i am using ruby version 2.7.5 ,  "Failure/Error: hash = lines.to_h { |x| x.split '=' }

ArgumentError:
  wrong array length at 84 (expected 2, was 3)
"

Comment: @Abr that's because one of the strings contains more than one `=`. You can limit [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.5/String.html#split-method) to 2 substrings via `x.split('=', 2)`

Comment: I see that some string contains, "name=sit::sit_id::"
,  "IP=192.165.0.1" and "test=nt1,nt2," , is this triggering error? error : Failure/Error: hash = lines.to_h { |x| x.split('=', 2)}

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `to_h' for #<String:0x0000557634649538>
  Did you mean?  to_f
                 to_r
                 to_i
                 to_s
                 to_d
                 to_c

Comment: @Abr the `ArgumentError` is caused by a string containing two `=` characters. It's the element at index 84 of your array. The other `NoMethodError` is unrelated to that problem. It occurred because you (accidentally) called `to_h` on a string.

Comment: ok i see, i changed limit but it seems one of string even dont contain "=", how you handle this?                    Failure/Error: hash = lines.to_h { |x| x.split('=', 2) }

ArgumentError:
  wrong array length at 93 (expected 2, was 0)

Comment: its just a empty sting at 93 "" , how you handle this, ?

Comment: ok i just used list = list.reject { |c| c.empty? }, first to get rid of empty ones, it worked Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the `list` and replace the number after `active=` like below:

```
list= ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]

list.each_with_index do |item, index|
  next unless item.starts_with?('active')

  number_with_active = item.split('active=')[1].to_i
  list[index] = "active=#{(number_with_active+1)%2}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest an entirely different approach; HOWEVER, the **main** problem with your original code is that you're using an inappropriate method right at the start.  `each` isn't returning a modified array.  Try using `map` instead.  At a minimum, you'll also want to add a line of code to ensure all other elements return unchanged.  If you don't, the other elements will be replaced with `nil` values.  Here's what your code might look like with minimal modifications:

```
list= ["beam=0", "active=0", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]

list.map do |lists|
   if lists.include?("active=0")
      lists = "active=1"
   elsif list.include?("active=1")
      lists = "active=0"
   else
      lists
   end
end

#=>  ["beam=0", "active=1", "rate=11", "version=4.1", "delay=5"]
```